# Obtaining the schema name and the table name at once

Tags: c#, sql

I'm about to present states that I have some tables and some stored procedures in a random database on an SQL server. These tables and SP's are named with the following formats:

`[schema name].[table name]`

and

```
[schema name].[sp name]
```

My task is to capture both of those values, either for a table name or for an SP.

I've executed the statement (which contains 4 SQL queries) below on C# and then by reading the outcoming values via the SqlDataReader, I thought I had matched the schema names with the table/SP names next to them. Most of them did anyway, but I need to have all of them matched correctly.

```
if (requestCode == 1)
{
    SetSpecificList("USE " + db_name + "; SELECT * FROM sys.tables", "USE " + db_name + "; SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES", tablesList, requestCode);
}
else if (requestCode == 2)
{
   SetSpecificList("USE " + db_name + "; SELECT * FROM sys.procedures", "USE " + db_name + "; SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES", SPList, requestCode);
}
```

How does one combine two SQL statements (simply one statement) for obtaining the full name of a table/SP, instead of dividing it as `[schema name][table name]`, in two queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would always be inclined to use the system catalog views over the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for reasons outlined [in this article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views), and I am not 100% sure why you are using both in this case...

Anyway, you can either use the `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME()` function, e.g.

```
SELECT  TableName = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
FROM    sys.tables AS t;
```

Or you could join to `sys.schemas`:

```
SELECT  TableName = QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
FROM    sys.tables AS t
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
            ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id;
```

For what it is worth though, you can get both procedures and tables (and all other objects) out from the same table:

```
SELECT  ObjectName = QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name),
        ObjectType = o.type_desc
FROM    sys.all_objects AS o
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
            ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE   o.[type] IN ('U', 'P');
```

Comment: I have used the second code snippet you've provided to me, and it works the way I need. Thank you!